# SELECT TYPE with unlimited polymorphic pointer to CHARACTER(*) variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

Following example uses `Fortran 2003` features for defining unlimited polymorphic pointers and performing actions based on the variable type following a `select type` construct. The subroutine `handleP` prints the value of the argument in dependence of it's type.

```
program example
    implicit none
    type name
        character(22) :: n
    end type

    character(len=7) :: mystring
    mystring = 'Initial'

    call handleP(mystring)
    call handleP('Initial')
    call handleP(name('Initial'))

    contains

        subroutine handleP(p)
            class(*), intent(in) :: p

            select type(p)
            type is (character(len=*))
                write(*,*) len(p), ': ', p
            class is (name)
                write(*,*) len(p%n), ': ', p%n
            class default
                write(*,*) 'Unknown type'
            end select
        end subroutine

end program example
```

Compiling with `gfortran` version 4.8 gives following output:

```
       7 : Initial
       0 :
      22 : Initial
```

So, with `call handleP(mystring)` everything works as expected, but with `call handleP('Initial')` the printing fails. Calling with a `type(name)` argument also works.

Is the behaviour with `call handleP('Initial')` a `gfortran` bug or am I doing something wrong? If it is a bug, what could I do to prevent it?

Comment: One of your type guard statements is a syntax error.  It uses an assumed length specification (the `*`) - that has to be deferred length (use a `:`).  If gfortran accepts this then that's a compiler bug.

Comment: @IanH Is deferred length true?  From F2008 4.4.3.2 "A char-length type parameter value of * has the following meanings... If used in the type-spec of a type guard statement, the associating entity assumes its length from the selector".  The NAG documentation also appears to support `*`.

Comment: You're right - I got my assumed and deferred mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. After some reading on gcc bugzilla, I assume that it is a `gfortran` bug. `Gfortran` seems to be not very capable of passing strings with polymorphic pointers yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to let everyone know that the issue is fixed under gFortran 4.9.3-1 which comes with current MinGW installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
program example
    implicit none
    type name1
        character(22) :: n
    end type

    character(len=7) :: mystring
    mystring = 'Initial'

    call handleP(mystring)
    call handleP('Initial')
    call handleP(name1('Initial'))

    contains

        subroutine handleP(p)
            class(*), intent(in) :: p

            select type(p)
            type is (character(len=*))
                write(*,*) len(p), ': ', p
            class is (name1)
                write(*,*) len(trim(adjustl(p%n))), ': ', p%n
            class default
                write(*,*) 'Unknown type'
            end select
        end subroutine

end program example
```

The second call doesn't work since 'Initial' is not a variable. The 22 before was just the length which you defined in the type declaration. So I adjusted the length of it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my questions was more on the second case. Now I'm quite sure that passing 'Initial' to `handleP` should be possible, because for real and integer numbers it works as well.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. Actually you are right. I just tried it. The intel compiler gives what you expected. B.t.w. with the PGI compiler I only get a Segmentation fault.